# how to change text color of tabs when pressed (currentTab)?

Tags: android

In my seTabColor() I'm setting the color of the title text to Gray. I want to change it to white when pressed. How can I do it?

```
public void setTabColor(TabHost tabHost) {
        for(int i = 0; i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
//          tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(r[i]);
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            TextView t = (TextView) getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            t.setTextSize(9 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
//          tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = 58;
//          tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).().height = 58;
            TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
```

}

I wanna do something like: `tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab())...`

But im not sure how to use that to conditionally change the text color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, look into defining your UI in XML if that's possible.

Take a look at [State List Drawable Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). You can define what image to use when a view is pressed, highlighted, etc. After defined, you can then use your XML file like any other resource.

Example:
    XML file saved at res/drawable/button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>

This layout XML applies the state list drawable to a Button:

<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804688/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-tabs-indicator-text-in-android/2805256#2805256), which in particular shows:

```
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/tab_indicator_text</item>
```

You can override that default `textColor` by creating your own color selector (create the `res/color/` directory in your project, and create a new file in there, called `tab_indicator_text.xml`), and changing the value above to match your own color selector (`@color/tab_indicator_text`).  The contents of the `tab_indicator_text.xml` file will be a selector list, like the one mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146037/android-tabstyle/4147358#4147358):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:color="#bfbfbf" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html just go there you waill come to know what u want to do.

tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

Comment: This is for changing background color of tab right,I want to change only textview color in tab.My tab contains image and textview.I want to change only textview color in tab